# how to return to start when iterating over array and iterator become larger than length (in a graphics render loop)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to make an animation recorder that records x,y positions into an array and allow the animation to be recalled. I specifically have p5.js in mind as the graphics lib, but any should work. since this is just array work.

in p5.js to return the value of Sin() or Cos() you can pass them an angle, that angle can be ever incrementing since 2PI == 4PI (in terms of the direction the rotation is facing) etc. I'm looking to replicate this kind of function but to return the data stored in an array.

so for example you've got an array like the following

```js
let demo = ['297', '298', '299', '300']
```

It would be easy to loop over the array once since it has 4 items, but I'd like to write a function where if we passed in 4, it would return index 0, '297' or if we fed in 11, it would return '300' or if we fed in 22 it would return '299'

this way the function could continually be fed in an ever increasing value that moves up each frame we could return the values of the array in a loop.

```js
let survey = 0;

let demo = ['297', '298', '299', '300']

//a rendering loop
function draw(){

survey ++

let xPos = getPosition(survey) //this getPosition function is the one in question

ellipse(xPos,100,50)

}
```

I feel like this is some modulo math, but I cant quite get it sorted.
thanks for taking a look!

Comment: Where's your demo of `getPosition`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to your problem is the modulus (`%`) operator. This operator will return the remainder of the division.

E.g. `11 % 4 = 3`

```js
const positions = [297, 298, 299, 300];

function getPosition(positions, i) {
  return positions[i % positions.length];
}

console.log(getPosition(positions, 4));  // 297
console.log(getPosition(positions, 11)); // 300
console.log(getPosition(positions, 22)); // 299
```